# WPF Combobox/Listview/Listview linking using WCF DataService

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, listview

I'm sorry if this question has been previously asked, but I have not found a solution.

Using the standard Northwind DataService, I have a Combobox displaying CustomerID, and from this I have a successful link to a Listview which displays the Orders associated with that CustomerID. However I have a second Listview that I would like to display the Order_Details that are associated with the SelectedItem in the Orders Listview, this ListView remains blank, and this is an error as it should have the Details of the selected Order. I need these populations to occur on 'Loaded'.

The salient table details are :
Customers (CustomerID), Orders(CustomerID, OrderID), Order_Details(OrderID).

Here is my xaml code :

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="Customer ID" />        
    <ComboBox Name="customerIDComboBox" 
              DisplayMemberPath="CustomerID" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
              SelectedIndex="0" />        

    <ListView Name="ordersListView" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Orders}"  
              DisplayMemberPath="OrderID" 
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
              SelectedItem="0" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=OrderID, Mode=OneWay}" 
                    Header="Order ID" Width="75"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=OrderDate, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    Header="Order Date" Width="150"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Freight, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                    Header="Freight Cost" Width="75"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <ListView Name="detailsListView" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Order_Details}"  
              DisplayMemberPath="OrderID" 
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
              SelectedItem="0" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=OrderID, Mode=OneWay}" 
                    Header="Order ID" Width="75"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProductID, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Header="Product ID" Width="75"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

There are some buttons, but they are not relevant to my issues.

Here is my code-behind :

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        context = new NorthwindEntities(new Uri(svcUri));

        var customerQuery = from cust in context.Customers.Expand("Orders/Order_Details")
                            select cust;

        trackedCustomers = new DataServiceCollection<Customer>(customerQuery, 
                                                             TrackingMode.AutoChangeTracking,
                                                              "Customers",
                                                               OnPropertyChanged,
                                                               OnCollectionChanged);
        this.LayoutRoot.DataContext = trackedCustomers;
    }
    catch (DataServiceQueryException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The query could not be completed:\n" + ex.ToString());
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The following error occurred:\n" + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: so ... what is your problem?

Comment: The problem is that the Combobox (Customers) and the first ListView (Orders) populate perfectly, however the ListView (Details) is blank.

Comment: Don't have the DB installed, and your question has lots of stuff I couldn't care less about (the width, min height, margins, etc, which just make it harder to read the code). Alas, is the omission of the `SelectedItem="0"` on the `detailsDataGrid` on purpose?

Comment: Yes, point taken on the readability; code amended accordingly.

Comment: The SelectedItem=0 has been added but makes no difference to the outcome. The SelectItem was tried and removed in the 'detailsListView', as it would be the final display item.

Comment: Not trying to be harsh, but do understand that you ask someone else to  sift through your 100+ lines of code with no context. Always remember that the problem is yours, and they are trying to help. So help them help you. Having said that, I couldn't find anything that seems seemingly wrong with what you've posted ... Hopefully someone else will soon :)

Comment: Thanks for looking. This is my first question ever to such forums and I apologize for my lack of etiquette, I will learn. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question I know, but it closes it.

```
<ListView Name="detailsListView" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Order_Details}"  
          DisplayMemberPath="OrderID" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
          SelectedItem="0" >
```

should be replaced with :

```
<ListView Name="detailsListView" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Orders/Order_Details}"  
          DisplayMemberPath="OrderID" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
          SelectedItem="0" >
```

This leads to correct population of the combobox/listbox/listbox.